# Clearing class definitions in MATLAB

Tags: oop, class, matlab

The command `clear classes` clears all class definitions loaded in memory at that time.

Is it possible to clear only specific class definitions?

EDIT: I'm interesting in removing specific class *definitions* from memory, not class instances.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran into this issue myself when I wrote my new HPF class. So I tried a few things, since as I was debugging the new class I had many changes to make, and then test out.

"Clear functions" does not help. I even tried "clear hpf". But clearing all instances does seem to do so. For example:

```
>> x = hpf(3);
>> x+2
ans =
5

>> whos
  Name      Size            Bytes  Class     Attributes

  ans       1x1               248  hpf                 
  x         1x1               248  hpf                 
  y         1x1                 8  double
```

So now I made a trivial change to the class and saved it.

```
>> z = hpf(17);
Warning: The class file for 'hpf' has been changed; but the change cannot be applied because objects based on the old class file still exist. If you use
those objects, you might get unexpected results. You can use the 'clear' command to remove those objects. See 'help clear' for information on how to remove
those objects. 

>> clear functions
>> clear hpf
>> clear x
>> clear z
>> x = hpf(3);
Warning: The class file for 'hpf' has been changed; but the change cannot be applied because objects based on the old class file still exist. If you use
those objects, you might get unexpected results. You can use the 'clear' command to remove those objects. See 'help clear' for information on how to remove
those objects.
```

So I still get a warning, telling me that MATLAB still has a problem. However, I still had an HPF instance in memory that is easily forgotten, ans.

```
>> clear ans
>> clear x
>> whos
  Name      Size            Bytes  Class     Attributes

  y         1x1                 8  double              

>> x = hpf(3);
>> x+23
ans =
26
```

As long as I removed that instance too, MATLAB no longer gives me a warning. Note that I never had to issue a "clear classes" command. The variable y, a double, still exists to prove that fact.

Comment: for completeness I'd like to add that instances can also hide in the userdata components of figures and other graphical objects. These don't show up with whos.

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn't a completely clean removal of the class definition. Constant property data remains in memory, for example, even after all instances have been deleted.

Answer (score 1):

This is one way to do it:

% Set `ClassName` to match the name of the class whose instances you wish to clear.

```
ClassName = 'MyClass';
```

% Here's the code:

```
VarsStruct = whos;
VarsCellArray = cat(3, cellstr(char(VarsStruct(:).name)), cellstr(char(VarsStruct(:).class)));
ClassInstanceIndices = find(ismember(VarsCellArray(:,:,2), ClassName));
ClassInstanceNames = VarsCellArray(ClassInstanceIndices,:,1)';
clear(ClassInstanceNames{:});
```

Comment: I'd like to clear the class *definitions*, not the class instances. Of course clearing the class instances first is absolutely essential but I already know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

To clear a class definition, including all Constant property data, it is necessary to do both of the following

1. clear all instances of the class from memory
2. Issue `clear classname`.

It must be done in the above order. Reversing the order will leave Constant property data stuck in memory (as of R2013b) until `clear classes` is issued.

Comment: `clear` should work fine for clearing individual instances regardless of what they contain.

Comment: *Yes, but in the context I described in the previous comment, it doesn't appear to work. Did you try it?* Many times. The property's delete() method should be called automatically when `clear` is applied. If you've hit an anomalous example, you should start a thread that demonstrates it so that it can be better examined. Nothing else mentioned is documented, AFAIK, but it's easy to test. Make a class instance with a Constant property containing a large array. On Windows, you can see in the Tsk Mgr that the memory from the Constant property is not de-allocated, even after deleting the object.

Comment: That's odd because I've also tried it many times. Assuming `myobj` is a (handle) class instance and `myproperty` is one of its properties that holds another (handle) class's instance, calling `clear myobj.myproperty` appears to do nothing. The same is true if `clear this.myproperty` is called from within one of `myobj`'s methods. However, calling `myobj.myproperty.delete` appears to actually delete the object as expected.

Comment: @niels  We don't know what "appears to do nothing" means to you. As I commented previously, you should really start a thread with explicit examples, including the method you are using to decide whether `clear` had an effect or not. Are you saying the Task Manager shows un-deallocated memory, or did you use some other test?

Comment: @niels There are 2 ways to see the necessity of Step 2. One is the test I described, i.e., using the Task Manager to see if Constant property memory has been de-allocated. The class can't be considered "cleared" until that memory is freed too. Another way is to use the `inmem` command. You will see that deleting all class instances does not remove classname from the list returned by `inmem` until you do `clear classname`.

Comment: You may replace "appears to do nothing" with "doesn't do the intended job". You can try the example with `myobj` provided above. Try `clear myobj.myproperty` then type `myobj.myproperty` to validate that `myproperty` hasn't changed at all.

Comment: You are right about MATLAB not clearing the class definition upon deleting the last instance of the class. MATLAB actually **updates** the class definition upon deletion of the last instance (which suffices for my purposes, this is the reason I accepted the answer of user85109 some time ago).

Comment: @niels I see now (regarding clearing myproperty). You cannot apply `clear` to individual properties of a class. Applying delete is possible, as you've pointed out. However, if `myobj.myproperty` contains the only instance of a certain handle class (no other shared copies), then `clear myobj` will not only clear myobj from memory, it will trigger the `delete` method of the handle object in `myobj.myproperty` as well.