# cannot update class definition in Matlab

Tags: matlab, class, persistence

I am running into an infuriating problem with Matlab, and an [earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10566533/clearing-class-definitions-in-matlab) to apparently the same problem didn't help me, unfortunately.  I apologize that the question is rather long - you need quite a bit of information to reproduce the problem (I tried to trim it as much as I could...)

The problem is this: No matter what I do, after I have used a class I cannot "make Matlab forget". Values used seem to be persistent, and edits to the class definition won't "stick".  In the latter case, the error message is:

> Warning: The class file for 'myClass' has been changed; but the change
>   cannot be applied because objects based on the old class file still
>   exist. If you use those objects, you might get unexpected results. You
>   can use the 'clear' command to remove those objects. See 'help clear'
>   for information on how to remove those objects.

I get that message even after

```
>> clear all
>> clear functions
>> clear ans
```

Somehow the class definition is persistent despite my attempts to clear it. To make matters worse, when I modify a value of an instance of the class, then clear it, the value is somehow not "forgotten".  To illustrate, here is the source code of `myClass`:

```
% a simple class definition that shows the problem that I cannot
% figure out how to redefine a class without restarting Matlab
classdef myClass < handle
    properties
        precursors = {'none'};
        numPre = {1};
        value = 1;
    end

    methods
        function obj = myClass(pre, num, val)
            % constructor
            if nargin > 0
                obj.precursors = pre;
                obj.numPre = num;
                obj.value = val;
            end
        end
        function v = sumVal(obj)
            % find the sum of the value of all precursors
            n = numel(obj.precursors);
            v = 0;
            for ii = 1:n
              pc = obj.precursors{ii};
              if isa(pc, 'myClass')
                  if ii==1
                      v = 0;
                  end
                  v = v + sumVal(pc) * obj.numPre{ii};
              else
                  v = obj.value;
              end
            end
        end
    end

    % only the following named instances may exist:
    enumeration
      grandpa   ({'none'},           {1},  1)
      father    ({myClass.grandpa},  {3}, -1)
      son       ({myClass.father},   {2}, -1) 
    end
end
```

In a fresh instance of Matlab, I do the following:

```
>> son = myClass.son;
>> sumVal(son)

ans = 

     6

>> grandpa = myClass.grandpa;
>> grandpa.value = 5;
>> sumVal(son)

ans =

    30
```

So far, so good. The `sumVal` function discovers the fathers and grandfathers, and the `sumVal` is computed correctly (6 * 1 in the first case, 6 * 5 in the second case).

Now I delete "everything" (I think):

```
>> clear all
>> clear functions
>> clear ans
```

And I create just one variable:

```
>> son = myClass.son;
```

Now comes the kicker - the unexpected answer

```
>> sumVal(son)

ans =

    30
```

When I inspect the variables loaded, I find

```
>> whos
Name    Size       Bytes  Class     Attributes

son      1x1         112  myClass
```

There is no `grandpa` instance, and the class definition file was not touched. Yet, the value of `grandpa` (which I created, then deleted) is somehow persistent.

And when I make a small change to the `myClass.m` file, and try to create a new variable (after a `clear all`), I get the message shown above.  All of which leads me to my question:

Where is Matlab hiding an instance of my class so that variables are persistent after a `clear all`, and how do I clear the workspace (without restarting) so the class definition is "reset"?

I don't know if it matters, but I'm using Matlab 7.14.0.739 (R2012a)

Comment: Have you tried `clear classes` as well?

Comment: @DavidK - when I do `clear all; clear classes` I get a `"Warning: Objects of 'myClass' class exist. Cannot clear this class or any of its super-classes."` And after that, `sumVal(son)` is still `30`...

Comment: Why would you expect `sumVal(son)` to not be 30 at any point? Are you attempting to rearrange the tree structure at run time?

Comment: @andrewJanke - I expected it to be 30 the first time - when I had initially set the value of `grandpa` to 5. What surprises me was that that value persisted after I had attempted to clear everything...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have an intermediate instance `myClass.father` that is not being destroyed by MATLAB. You have to `delete`it yourself

```
>> clear grandpa
>> delete(son.precursors{1})
>> clear son
>> clear classes
>> son = myClass.son
son = 
    son    
>> sumVal(son)
ans =
     6
```

Edit: 
Alternatively, you can add a destructor to your class

```
    function delete(obj)
        if isa(obj.precursors{1}, 'myClass')
            delete(obj.precursors{1});
        end
    end
```

and use `delete(son)` instead of leaving it to `clear` function to destroy. You can extend this to your case and recursively delete all instances in your tree.

Comment: Brilliant! This discovery hits at the heart of my problem! You show a specific way of clearing the workspace in this case; but is there a way of ferreting out these hidden instances (the real class tree is a lot more complicated - do I have to create my own `destroyClass` method to kill them all? Can you even do that from inside the class itself?

Comment: You can add a destructor to take care of intermediate objects. I updated the answer to illustrate that for the example at hand.

Comment: We're getting closer. I am still able to get in trouble. I can create `son` without first creating `father` - and if I then try to delete `son` I get an error (because `obj.precursors{1}` doesn't exist). The same problem arises if I delete objects in the wrong order. My problem now is that I have gotten into a state where Matlab complains objects of the old class exist, but none of your techniques work - even if I create a new `father` and `son`, when I delete `son` it complains the precursor doesn't exist. Back to the core question: how do I find (list, enumerate) the hidden objects?

Comment: One more discovery: issuing a `rehash` seems to "clean up lost objects" - after that things behave again. Not clear why that should be so. Some helpful information also at http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/51648-unable-to-clear-classes . It seems to suggest that some of the behavior I am seeing may be a bug that's fixed in a later version of Matlab...

Comment: When you're calling `delete()` on these things, it's modifying the shared enumerated instances in the class itself, not local copies of them. So you're effectively corrupting your enumerated objects. This is probably not the real fix.

Comment: @AndrewJanke In this case there is no local copy of `myClass.father` therefore we need to delete it using the reference we have in `son.precursors{1}`. Of course it will be corrupted at that stage, but it is not being used, it's being destroyed and recreated again, therefore that corrupt state is not an issue.

Answer (score 2):

Those instances are "hiding" in the myClass enumeration class itself. Matlab is storing a reference to each of those named instances so when you reference them like `myClass.father` you get the same object back, instead of it constructing a new one. Probably similar to how values are stored in `Constant` properties on classes.

If you have any other classes that refer to the `myClass.xxx` enumerated instances in `Constant` properties, enumerations, or `persistent` variables, they could also be holding on to references to them.

Try doing `clear classes` a few times in a row instead of just once.

To help debug this, you could put a couple debugging `printf()` statements in the constructor and destructor for this class, so you can see when the instances are really created and cleaned up.

```
  function obj = myClass(pre, num, val)
      % constructor
      if nargin > 0
          obj.precursors = pre;
          obj.numPre = num;
          obj.value = val;
      end
      printf('myClass: created (%d, %d, nargin=%d)\n', obj.numPre, obj.value, nargin);
  end
  function delete(obj)
      printf('myClass: deleting (%d, %d)\n', obj.numPre, obj.value);
  end
```

Comment: It is true that multiple calls to `clear classes` seems to work but that is very unsatisfactory. I will try your debugging trick to get a better handle on this. My actual class is more complex - there are multiple paths to the same ancestor for example. I have found that the only robust solution so far is a script that calls `delete()` on every I stance of my class (there are over 20) "manually". I wish I could get a list of all instances in memory.

Comment: What do you find unsatisfactory about repeating `clear classes`?

Comment: You could probably get a list of all the enumeration instances with `m = enumeration('myClass')`. See http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/enumeration.html. That would allow you to process them in a loop instead of "manually" doing each one.

Comment: I like your most recent suggestion - delete all instances in a loop. I knew I could get this list (of all the possible enumerations of the class) - but hadn't thought of looping through to delete. What I am still hoping to find is "the list of hidden instances of the class" that are throwing these warnings (and that are preventing me from editing my class file and testing the result without some hocus pocus). Obviously Matlab has this list - or it wouldn't have thrown the warning in the first place. How do I get it to surrender that information?...

Comment: As for your other comment: "What do you find unsatisfactory..." - the fact that `clear classes` doesn't do a good job of clearing the classes is what I find most inelegant. I am hoping (but hope is fading) that Matlab is better than that... and that I just haven't found the right command yet.